# Rmarkdown: How to make available R dataframes derived in R chunks in global environment so that they can be re-used in other R chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am making a few derivations in one R chunk so that I can plot a graph with derived fields. 
The graph is then displayed nicely in my Rmarkdown document.

A bit further in my document I want to describe a few statistics on the derived fields but my derived dataframes are not available in the global environment. I can't consequently not derive the stats without redoing all the derivation again.

I clearly miss something here.. 
How can I make available the derived dataframes from a R chunk so that they can be re-used in another chunk?

EDIT: putting below a reproducible example as suggested. 
Doing so I noticed that cars2 derived in the R chunk is available as I could derive the mean speed using cars2. 
The confusing part is that if I knit it; it does not make cars2 visible in the global environment (empty). Not seeing the dataframe in the global environment I assumed it was not available but apparently it is. 
Still interested though to make it visible in global environment when knitting. Any idea of how to proceed

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Lionrolll"
date: "8 janvier 2020"
output: html_document
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
summary(cars)
cars2<-cars
```

```
The mean speed is `r mean(cars$speed)`. 

The mean speed is `r mean(cars2$speed)`.
```

[image: Evidence of car2 not visible in the global environment window after knitting the .Rmd file]

Comment: Hmmm...all objects assigned in previous chunks of Rmarkdown should be retained in global environment. If using RStudio, do you not see those named objects in environment panel? Please provide [mcve] that includes actual code of derivations/plot chunk and stats chunk. And post any errors verbatim. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds as though you are working in RStudio, and not running the code in all the chunks.  If that's the case, then you should click on the downward pointing "Run all chunks above" icon on the top right of the chunk you want to experiment with.

Comment: If you knit the document as a whole, you 'create a new global environment' for running your document. The objects in the first chunks, are available to the later chuncks. I think you want to run the chuncks in your notebook/markdown individually, to have them available..

Comment: @Parfait I provided a simplified reproducible example. That made obvious that the derived dataframes could be re-used later on when knitting the entire Rmd file. However, when looking at the global environment window the derived data frame is not present. For transparency do you know how to make it visible in that window when knitting the .Rmd file?

Comment: @arcoutte Do you mean that knitting generates an alternative global environment different from the one displayed by default? Do you know if there is a way to see that alternative global environment? For note, I edited the original question with simplified reproducible code and better description of what I was doing (knitting indeed).

Comment: as @user2554330 stated, you can run the chunks in your notebook itself by clicking the green triangle on the right-top of each chunck. Or use ´rmarkdown::render()` directly, because Rstudio indeed creates a new R session when you knit your document. Why would you want to be able to access the objects there?

Comment: @Arcoutte I would like to have them visible directly as some steps take some time and I don't want to lose time/resource re-running them chunk by chunk. And I want to be able to see intermediate steps for development purpose. That will allow me to cross checks different values generate and check step by step

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the green arrows (running chunck by chunck) can help you with, if I understand well. E.g. line 12 on your printshot on the right side of your console window. This will run that specific chunck and you wil find cars2 in your global env; (given cars existed ofcourse)l